# Estimating minPts in DBSCAN for document layout clustering

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I am trying to choose parameters for DBSCAN clustering algorithm, in particular *minPts*.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN#Parameter_estimation) suggests a rule of thumb to derive *minPts* from the number of dimensions *D* in the data set. *minPts* >= *D* + 1. For larger datasets, with much noise, it suggests *minPts* = 2 * *dim*. I guess *D* and *dim* stands for the same, do they?

I wonder what is the value of *D* in my case?

I use DBSCAN for clustering 2-dimensional black-and-white scans of business documents based on their layout. First, each scan gets segmented into black-and-white boxes and then turned into 0-1 1-dimensional arrays (strings). Here's an example of a segmented document scan.

[image: Segmented image]

I use Levenstein distance in clustering to measure similarity between scans.

So I guess my *D* = 1 and I should start with *minPts* = 2?